# cannot convert from string to float after read from .csv file and store in hash table

Tags: c++, string, file, terminal, hashtable

I read data from csv file as a string using "getline( )" method and then I store it in hash table but some data are in float. I want to **convert from string to float** and store in hash table.

I try to import #include <bits/stdc++.h> library and use stof() to convert from string to float but I still doesn't work.

It showed "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
what():  stof" in terminal.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct student {
    string id;
    string name;
    string gender;
    string department;
    float score;
};
student stu[2000];

int hash_function(string s){
    int total = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<s.size(); i++){
        total = total + (int) s[i];
    }
    return total%2000;
}



void display(){
    for(int i=0; i<2000; i++){
        cout << "Position " << i << ": " << stu[i].id << " " << stu[i].name << " " << stu[i].gender << " " << stu[i].department << " " << stu[i].score << endl;
    }
}

main(){
    fstream myfile;
    string line;
    string data[5];
    float score[1];

    myfile.open("I3list.csv", ios::in);


    while(getline(myfile, line)){
       //cout << line << endl;
       int i = 0;
       stringstream s(line);
       while(getline(s, data[i], ',')){
            //cout << data[i] << endl;
            i = i + 1;

            int index;
            index = hash_function(data[1]);
            stu[index].id = data[0];
            stu[index].name = data[1];
            stu[index].gender = data[2];
            stu[index].department = data[3];
            stu[index].score = stof(data[4]);
       }
    }
    display();
    myfile.close();
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?  If you learned that from a website, block that website and never go there again.  If you learned that from a book, burn the book.  If you learned that from a friend, you'll have to unfriend them.

Comment: Please provide example of input file `"I3list.csv"`.

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: please show a [mre], the exception suggests the value you are passing to `std::stof` isn't a floating point value. Have you tried using a debugger? Have you tried catching the exception?

Comment: And please show us a short example of the file you attempt to read, copy-paste the first five lines into your question.

Comment: Here is version tweaked so it runs on godbolt. Input data are still needed: https://godbolt.org/z/d7hPMxT1v

Comment: `index = hash_function(data[1]);` this doesn't make seance! What it suppose to do?

Comment: I think you want a closing bracket after `i = i + 1;` so you read all 5 fields first _then_ store them.

Comment: This is "C++" not "C" so use `std::vector<student> students;`  instead of `student stu[2000];` (giving your variables good readable names is important too). And to add students to this resizable array (that's what std::vector is) use `students.push_back(student);`

Comment: Also having global variables is a bad design practice you'd best unlearn right from the start. Add `std::vector<student> students` to your main and pass it as `const std::vector<student>&` to any function that needs access to it.

Comment: Consider adding a `>>` overload to `student` The code will be a lot easier to work with when you can `s >> tempstudent;` or even `while (myfile >> tempstudent)`.

Answer (score 0):

At some point in the loop, `stof(data[4])` does not contain a valid string representation of a float.

It's hard to see what the issue is exactly without the actual CSV file, but what you can do is catch the exception and print `data[4]` so you can see what exactly it is you are trying to convert to a float.

Here is an example:

```
        ...        
        stu[index].name = data[1];
        stu[index].gender = data[2];
        stu[index].department = data[3];

        try {
            stu[index].score = stof(data[4]);
        } catch (const std::invalid_argument& e) {
            // print an error message
            cerr << "Error converting " << data[4] << "to float: " << endl;
        }
```

This won't fix your issue, but most likely you will see that data[4] contains some "non-float" string. If this doesn't help resolve the issue, include some part of your CSV so that I can actually reproduce the problem.

Also: I advise against using `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`.